# Issue with LaTeX and Markdown Tables in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 and having an issue with LaTeX in Markdown tables. When I create a table that contains math typeset in LaTeX, the Notebook (sometimes!) renders the table so that the table spans the entire width of the Notebook. I attach a screenshot of a minimal example.

[image]

In the first example, the top row is a simple x in math model. The top row of the table is left-justified and the next row is right-justified creating a table that spans the Notebook and table elements that don’t align.

In the second example, without x in math mode, the table renders as expected.

This behavior is new; affecting tables that I’ve created that previously rendered properly. The problem isn't consistent either. Some tables with LaTeX that I've made do in fact render properly.

I would appreciate advice for a work-around or where to post this issue so that it can be resolved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a workaround, use display mode for the math:

```
| $$x$$ |
| :---- |
| 0     |
```

Answer (score 3):

It makes a difference if you use one or two `$`-signs.

This will not expand, because it will activate the display mode for math, which is always centered

```
|$$x$$|
|-|
|0|
```

while this will activate the inline code.

```
|$x$|
|-|
|0|
```

**Example Output**

[image: how latex is rendered]

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to workaround is to add one row with empty latex display mode.

```
| $x$  |
| ---  |
| 0    |
| $$$$ |
```