# Last column of table in Jupyter Notebook Markdown cell badly formatted

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I created this table in jupyter notebook markdown cell, but the last column is badly formatted and I can not figure out what the problem is.

```
| $H_0$ | $H_1$ | Test statistic TS | Significance level $\alpha$ test | $p$-value |
| :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
| $\beta_1 = 0$ | $\beta_1\neq 0$ | $\frac{\hat\beta_1}{s/\sqrt{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}}$ | Reject if $|TS|> t_{\alpha/2, n-2}$ | $2P(t(n-2) \geq |TS|)$ |
```

[image: Rendered output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you aren't using JupyterLab because presently it works **generally**, as-is there. (I qualify it with 'generally' because your example is very complex, unlike the minimal reproducible example in the place I found the solution. I note the `Reject if` portion of the fourth column may not be perfect with your original code in JupyterLab, see below. I may have missed more)

Presumably then you aren't using JupyterLab and aren't looking to change, and so the solution is (and **probably even best in JupyterLab, too**):

As covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66014936/8508004) in reply to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66014726/8508004), (which was also posted at the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/issue-with-latex-in-markdown-tables/7717)), it seems to differ whether you use one or two dollar signs when embedding the latex in a table. You used only one dollar sign throughout yours, and the referenced solution said you need two.

I copied your included text and in a text-editor did find-replace to change every single dollar sign in your markdown table to double dollar sign to get:

```
| $$H_0$$ | $$H_1$$ | Test statistic TS | Significance level $$\alpha$$ test | $$p$$-value |
| :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
| $$\beta_1 = 0$$ | $$\beta_1\neq 0$$ | $$\frac{\hat\beta_1}{s/\sqrt{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}}$$ | Reject if $$|TS|> t_{\alpha/2, n-2}$$ | $$2P(t(n-2) \geq |TS|)$$ |
```

I see, in the current traditional Jupyter notebook interface, the following where the top is your markdown text rendered and the bottom is where I did find-replace to change every single dollar sign to double:

[image]

This approach works in JupyterLab, too, and so is probably best for use everywhere. Indeed, the `Reject if` portion of the fourth column works better in Jupyterlab (I think), too, with this updated approach.

Comment: Worked like magic! Thanks