# Jupyter Notebook and Lab can not render this markdown snippet from Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

This is how it looks on Google Colab when rendered,
[image: screenshot from colab]

**The actual script**

```
# Notation
Here is a summary of some of the notation you will encounter.  

|General <img width=70/> <br />  Notation  <img width=70/> | Description<img width=350/>| Python (if applicable) |
|: ------------|: ------------------------------------------------------------||
| $a$ | scalar, non bold                                                      ||
| $\mathbf{a}$ | vector, bold                                                      ||
| **Regression** |         |    |     |
|  $\mathbf{x}$ | Training Example feature values (in this lab - Size (1000 sqft))  | `x_train` |   
|  $\mathbf{y}$  | Training Example  targets (in this lab Price (1000s of dollars)).  | `y_train` 
|  $x^{(i)}$, $y^{(i)}$ | $i_{th}$Training Example | `x_i`, `y_i`|
| m | Number of training examples | `m`|
|  $w$  |  parameter: weight,                                 | `w`    |
|  $b$           |  parameter: bias                                           | `b`    |     
| $f_{w,b}(x^{(i)})$ | The result of the model evaluation at $x^{(i)}$ parameterized by $w,b$: $f_{w,b}(x^{(i)}) = wx^{(i)}+b$  | `f_wb` |
```

However, in my local Jupyter Notebook/Lab it doesn't render correctly, I installed these extensions in Jupyter Lab
[image]
still it won't render and looks something like this
[image: screenshot from Jupyter Lab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below, as it is close:

```
# Notation
Here is a summary of some of the notation you will encounter.  

| General <br>  Notation   <br />   | Description |  Python (if applicable)     |
| :-:       |    :----:   |         :- |
| $$a$$     | scalar, non bold        ||
| $$\mathbf{a}$$ | vector, bold                                                      ||
| **Regression** |         |    |     |
|  $$\mathbf{x}$$ | Training Example feature values (in this lab - Size (1000 sqft))  | `x_train` |   
|  $$\mathbf{y}$$  | Training Example  targets (in this lab Price (1000s of dollars)).  | `y_train` 
|  $$x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}$$ | $$i_{th}$$Training Example | `x_i`, `y_i`|
| m | Number of training examples | `m`|
|  $$w$$  |  parameter: weight,                                 | `w`    |
|  $$b$$           |  parameter: bias                                           | `b`    |     
| $$f_{w,b}(x^{(i)})$$ | The result of the model evaluation at $$x^{(i)}$$ parameterized by $$w,b$$: $$f_{w,b}(x^{(i)}) = wx^{(i)}+b$$  | `f_wb` |
```

Yields in classic notebook in session launched [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements):

[image]

Most of the issue is explained by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74693766/8508004); it seems you need to use double dollar signs when embedding latex in a table. So for all but the first few rows, I simply did find replace to double the dollar sign symbols, and then pasted that in. ( I later realized I needed to hand edit the `$$x^{(i)}, y^{(i)}$$` line.) The first few rows I did by hand trying to understand how they matched and attempting to control the alignment.

I cannot say what is going on with the alignment. According to [here](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/) and even using that code there's a way to align left the first column. It kept messing up the table though incorporating that and the latex.