# Markdown with latex not working in Jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I've a markdown cell with some latex code in a notebook file but for some reason it doesn't display correctly. Tried it in VSCode and Jupyter Notebook and installed Mactex - have mac - but that didn't help either. Anything I'm missing ?

[image]

Comment: Please include the code as well not just a screenshot. Note under 'Help others reproduce the problem' at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it specifically discourages what you did. **Latex/MathJax is working or the math formulas & equations wouldn't display like that.** Tables markdown with Latex/markdown can be tricky and I think that is your issue. It would be possible to troubleshoot with the code.

Comment: Wait! I knew that table content looked familiar. Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook and Lab can not render this markdown snippet from Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293544/jupyter-notebook-and-lab-can-not-render-this-markdown-snippet-from-google-colab) . (Note that in my last comment I meant to write, "Tables markdown with Latex/ **MathJax** can be tricky", with what I meant to type in bold.)